# Handling Cache for time sensative data with OpenLiteSpeed Cache

Tags: wordpress, caching, litespeed

I have WordPress setup on OpenLiteSpeed Digital Ocean Droplet with LiteSpeed Cache plugin installed.

I have created a shortcode which display all the meeting that are scheduled. These individual event cards have countdown on them. Now, after the page has cached, the event card doesn't get removed. Only When I purge cache manually it does get removed or I do a hard refresh.

Researching for this topic I found this [article](https://blog.litespeedtech.com/2018/12/12/wordpress-shortcodes-esi-blocks/) which explains how to use ESI blocks to tackle it but I am unable to set it up.

Comment: OLS doesn't support ESI  , you will need to either convert it to LiteSpeed Enterprise , or use QUIC cloud to get ESI feature.

Comment: Is using ESI the only option, when using litespeed. ?

Comment: not exactly sure what is your use case here  ,  if event is not on real time countdown (like time collapses at each second) but only show up in particular date/time , then you can try set cache TTL for this page to lower TTL , or use something like ajax call to get the content , ajax call won't be cached , nor it will be affected